# Flutter http.delete method returns status 401 when using Workmanager, but works when calling it directly

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, http

I have a flutter application which has a logout function. The session is timed out after some time so the logout needs to happen in the background.

I have tried using flutter workmanager for this, but when i call the http.delete method with workmanager i get statuscode 401. If i put the method in a direct function (for example with a button click) then it works and i get respone 200.

This is happening on android device. I have not tried iOS yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the app have a token for logout? Maybe after 15 min it's expired and fails